# What's preventing IO flush in my code?

Tags: haskell

I tried solving [this](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p2), and the following is trial stuff.

When I test this in ghci with `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`, `solveAct 1`, `15 10`, ghci showed few lines of results and blocked much time, and showed rest result at once.

How can I see the intermediate results in real time?

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO

readInts = fmap read . words <$> getLine :: IO [Int]

main = do
  t <- readLn :: IO Int
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  sequence_ $ solveAct <$> [1..t]

showTable x = intercalate "\n" $ intercalate " " . fmap show <$> x

solveAct i = do
  [j, n] <- readInts
  putStrLn $ "Case #" ++ show i ++ ":"
  putStrLn $ showTable (take n $ solve (j-1))

digits n = [[x ^ y | y <- [1..n-1]] | x <- [2..10]]

primes = 2 : [x | x <- [3,5..], all (\y -> x `rem` y /= 0) $ takeWhile (<= intSqrt x) primes]

intSqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
getNDivisor n = listToMaybe [x | x <- takeWhile (<= intSqrt n) primes, n `rem` x == 0]

casesOfMat = subsequences . transpose . digits
casesOfJam n = fmap ([1 + x^n | x <- [2..10]]:) $ casesOfMat n
eachBaseReps n = fmap sum . transpose <$> casesOfJam n

solve :: Int -> [[Int]]
solve n = do
  decimals <- eachBaseReps n
  let divs = getNDivisor <$> decimals
  guard $ all isJust divs
  return $ last decimals : catMaybes divs
```

Comment: You might also like `sequence :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]`, which returns `Just xs` exactly when all the elements of its input are `Just`s. Then you can wrap your `all isJust` check and `catMaybes` operation into a single `case` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* seeing the results in real time. It's just that the computation of `all isJust . map getNDivisor` takes a long time for the third element of `eachBaseReps 14`.

Comment: Thanks for answer and your comment. You are right and I have a question. If it was C code then I could use pause while debugging. Is there any correspondent to this?

Comment: @jeiea ghci has a debugger built in. The manual has a decent introduction to using it that I encourage you to check out. In regards to your precise question, there is `threadDelay`, though it is in `IO` and therefore cannot be used in pure code.